# FooTable doesn't work in ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, footable

I'm trying to using FooTable in a ruby on rails project (I've never used FooTable before) but I can't make it work.

I've inserted `gem 'footable-on-rails'` in my gemfile (and ran bundle install)

I've inserted `footable.js` in `app/vendor/assets/javascript` and also in `app/assets/javascript` (which is the best/right location?)

I've inserted `footable.core.css` in  `app/vendor/assets/stylesheet` and also in `app/assets/stylesheet`

I've created this file called `footable_init.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("table").footable();
});
```

I also changed my `application.js` file to:

```
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require bootstrap.min
    //= require footable-on-rails
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery-ui
    //= require jquery_ujs

//= require_tree .
```

And my `application.css`

```
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require footable-on-rails
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Note I'm also using bootstrap.

Finally my view looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'footable.core.css' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'footable.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'footable_init.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Age</th>
                </tr>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Luke</td>
                <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amy</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carl</td>
                <td>25</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>     
</html>
```

But when I pass to phone or tablet resolution I see both column.
What am I missing?

I thought it would have been easy to include FooTable in my rails project but it's taking me too much time.
Thank in advance.

Comment: can you link to the gem repository?

Comment: also, you don't have to insert the JS and CSS files manually since the gem does this for you. Delete the files and see if that helps

Comment: https://github.com/riandrea/FooTable-On-Rails

Answer (score 0):

You added `footable.js` three times instead of once. The gem already includes the JavaScript by adding `require 'footable-on-rails'` in your application.js. The same goes for  your CSS files.

There is no need to add them both in the `app` or the `vendor` directory. Remove those files and see if that helps.

Also, you have to include your application files. According to [the asset pipeline docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) add

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

to your application layout.

Comment: Do I also have to remove footable.core.css files from app and vendor directory?

Comment: Yes, the same goes for CSS

Comment: It still doesn't work. Is it necessary to include all those javascript files in my view file?

Comment: remove those lines as well, you cannot include what doesn't exist - instead include the application files, I updated my answer